# django rest framework + djoser ошибка при получении токена - "non_field_errors": [ "Невозможно войти с предоставленными учетными данными." ]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Для выполнения авторизации по токену использую модуль djoser все работало ок  пока я не заполнил у модели User поле groups ( при этом со старым токеном тоже все работало ) после этого я вышел из системы и теперь при попытке получить новый токен получаю следующую ошибку

> "non_field_errors": ["Невозможно войти с предоставленными учетными данными."]

В тоже время когда меняю права с `IsAdminUser` на `AllowAny` т.е снимаю необходимость авторизации и получения токена все работает ок  информация в инете по этому поводу данной ситуации  очень скудная помогите пжста
Доп информация: из админ панели токен создается без проблем и я с ним могу работать через postman командами джоссер (API) а именно получать инфу о пользователе   выход с удалением токена

сериализер:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'groups' )
```

представление:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser, )
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем привет нашел проблему к сожалению сразу не обратил внимание на сообщение терминала:

```
Bad Request: /auth-token/token/login
[09/Feb/2023 22:27:37] "POST /auth-token/token/login HTTP/1.1" 400 125
[09/Feb/2023 22:27:37] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('----------------------------657294765975348240526007')
[09/Feb/2023 22:27:37] "----------------------------657294765975348240526007" 400 -
```

нашел синтаксическую ошибку - отсутствовала одна галочка в хэдере запроса POST в Postman